# Please make my table perfect with long caption

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, captions, vertical-alignment

Question: I want to ask to question here first adjust the vertical and horizontal alignment of cells and second adjust the position of caption so table looks perfect.

Please help me. This is what I have right now.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=0.6 in,bottom=0.6 in,left=0.6 in,right=0.6 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\large
\begin{table}[]
\caption{Skin-friction co-efficient $Re_{x^{1/2}}C_{F_x}$ with linear stretching $n=1$ and non-linear stretching $n=1.5$ at $A=0.2$, $N_{r}=0.4$, $H=2$, $P_{r}=0.71$, $S_{c}=0.22$, $D_{f}=0.5$ and $S_{r}=1$}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|cc|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{$M$} & \multirow{2}{*}{$\gamma$} & \multirow{2}{*}{$\Tilde{N}$} & \multirow{2}{*}{$\lambda$} & \multirow{2}{*}{$k_{1}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$Re_{x^{1/2}}C_{F_x}$}                         \\ \cline{6-7} 
                     &                      &                      &                      &                      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$G$}          & $H$          \\ \hline
1.1                  & 1                    & 1                    & 1.2                  & 0.5                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.3664295040} & 0.6593644125 \\ \hline
1.2                  & 1                    & 1                    & 1.2                  & 0.5                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.3415189701} & 0.6363362691 \\ \hline
1.3                  & 1                    & 1                    & 1.2                  & 0.5                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.3101361584} & 0.6292554996 \\ \hline
1                    & 1.1                  & 1                    & 1.2                  & 0.5                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.3642452938} & 0.6515014440 \\ \hline
1                    & 1.2                  & 1                    & 1.2                  & 0.5                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.3619918988} & 0.6444405649 \\ \hline
1                    & 1                    & 1.1                  & 1.2                  & 0.5                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.4139365457} & 0.7091621892 \\ \hline
1                    & 1                    & 1.2                  & 1.2                  & 0.5                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.4613301362} & 0.7588005786 \\ \hline
1                    & 1                    & 1                    & 1.3                  & 0.5                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.4660386532} & 0.7627708751 \\ \hline
1                    & 1                    & 1                    & 1.4                  & 0.5                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.5649027509} & 0.8652549292 \\ \hline
1                    & 1                    & 1                    & 0.2                  & 0.6                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.3921955746} & 0.7029730388 \\ \hline
1                    & 1                    & 1                    & 0.2                  & 0.7                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.4025037653} & 0.7326143623 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: It's possible to replace `top=0.6 in,bottom=0.6 in,left=0.6 in,right=0.6 in` with the more succinct string `margin=0.6in`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest giving some more air to the table by increasing the intercolumn space, otherwise the very short column headers make for too compact typesetting.

Another improvement is avoiding vertical rules and `\multirow`: the first six headers are at the same level as the common header for the final two columns. Using `siunitx` helps a lot with numeric tables.

Note that `article` is set up for captions *below* tables. If you want the reverse, load `caption`.

Another suggestion is *never* using `\begin{document}\large`; 12pt size is already quite big. If you really need 14pt size, load `extarticle`.

Final details: `\Tilde` does nothing different from `\tilde`; for the Reynolds number, use `\mathit{Re}` rather than `Re`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=0.6 in,bottom=0.6 in,left=0.6 in,right=0.6 in]{geometry}

\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption{Skin-friction coefficient $\mathit{Re}_{x^{1/2}}C_{F_x}$ with linear 
  stretching $n=1$ and non-linear stretching $n=1.5$ at $A=0.2$, $N_{r}=0.4$, 
  $H=2$, $P_{r}=0.71$, $S_{c}=0.22$, $D_{f}=0.5$ and $S_{r}=1$}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2\tabcolsep}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  S[table-format=1.1]
  S[table-format=1.1]
  S[table-format=1.1]
  S[table-format=1.1]
  S[table-format=1.1]
  S[table-format=1.10]
  S[table-format=1.10]
  @{}
}
\toprule
{$M$} & {$\gamma$} & {$\tilde{N}$} & {$\lambda$} & {$k_{1}$} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$\mathit{Re}_{x^{1/2}}C_{F_x}$} \\
\cmidrule(l{\tabcolsep}){6-7}
&&&&& {$G$} & {$H$} \\
\midrule
1.1 & 1   & 1   & 1.2 & 0.5 & 0.3664295040 & 0.6593644125 \\
1.2 & 1   & 1   & 1.2 & 0.5 & 0.3415189701 & 0.6363362691 \\
1.3 & 1   & 1   & 1.2 & 0.5 & 0.3101361584 & 0.6292554996 \\
1   & 1.1 & 1   & 1.2 & 0.5 & 0.3642452938 & 0.6515014440 \\
1   & 1.2 & 1   & 1.2 & 0.5 & 0.3619918988 & 0.6444405649 \\
1   & 1   & 1.1 & 1.2 & 0.5 & 0.4139365457 & 0.7091621892 \\
1   & 1   & 1.2 & 1.2 & 0.5 & 0.4613301362 & 0.7588005786 \\
1   & 1   & 1   & 1.3 & 0.5 & 0.4660386532 & 0.7627708751 \\
1   & 1   & 1   & 1.4 & 0.5 & 0.5649027509 & 0.8652549292 \\
1   & 1   & 1   & 0.2 & 0.6 & 0.3921955746 & 0.7029730388 \\
1   & 1   & 1   & 0.2 & 0.7 & 0.4025037653 & 0.7326143623 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Math-Man For negative numbers, use `S[table-format=-a.b]`, where `a` is the number of digits in the integral part and `b` the number of digits in the fractional part; for instance, `S[table-format=-1.11]`.

Answer (score 6):

Some suggestions, in no partiular order: (a) Use a `threeparttable` environment to encase both the `\caption` statement and the `tabular` environment. That way, the width of the caption will be limited to that of the `table` body. (b) Employ the `S` column type (provided by the `siunitx` package) to align the numbers in the 7 data columns on their explicit or implicit decimal markers. (c) Give the table a much more open and inviting look by getting rid of all vertical rules (yes, really!) and using fewer, but well-spaced horizontal rules. (d) Load the `caption` package and employ the `skip` parameter to control the vertical separation below the caption.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{threeparttable} % for threeparttable environment
\usepackage{siunitx}        % for S column type
\usepackage{booktabs}       % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage[skip=0.5\baselineskip]{caption}

\begin{document}
\large %% are you sure you need this?

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}

\caption{Skin-friction co-efficient $Re_{x^{1/2}}C_{F_x}$, with linear stretching 
$n=1$ and non-linear stretching $n=1.5$. Other parameter settings: 
$A=0.2$, $N_{r}=0.4$, $H=2$, $P_{r}=0.71$, $S_{c}=0.22$, 
$D_{f}=0.5$, and $S_{r}=1$.}

\begin{tabular}{@{} *{5}{S[table-format=1.1]} 
                    *{2}{S[table-format=1.10,group-digits=false]} 
                @{}}
\toprule
{$M$} & {$\gamma$} & {$\widetilde{N}$} & {$\lambda$} & {$k_{1}$} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$Re_{x^{1/2}} C_{F_x}$} \\ 
\cmidrule(l){6-7} 
& & & & & {$G$} & {$H$}  \\ 
\midrule
1.1 & 1   & 1   & 1.2 & 0.5 & 0.3664295040 & 0.6593644125 \\ 
1.2 & 1   & 1   & 1.2 & 0.5 & 0.3415189701 & 0.6363362691 \\ 
1.3 & 1   & 1   & 1.2 & 0.5 & 0.3101361584 & 0.6292554996 \\ \addlinespace
1   & 1.1 & 1   & 1.2 & 0.5 & 0.3642452938 & 0.6515014440 \\ 
1   & 1.2 & 1   & 1.2 & 0.5 & 0.3619918988 & 0.6444405649 \\ 
1   & 1   & 1.1 & 1.2 & 0.5 & 0.4139365457 & 0.7091621892 \\ 
1   & 1   & 1.2 & 1.2 & 0.5 & 0.4613301362 & 0.7588005786 \\ \addlinespace
1   & 1   & 1   & 1.3 & 0.5 & 0.4660386532 & 0.7627708751 \\ 
1   & 1   & 1   & 1.4 & 0.5 & 0.5649027509 & 0.8652549292 \\ 
1   & 1   & 1   & 0.2 & 0.6 & 0.3921955746 & 0.7029730388 \\ 
1   & 1   & 1   & 0.2 & 0.7 & 0.4025037653 & 0.7326143623 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Hm, it is still unclear to me what is `perfect table" for you :-(. This is very opinion dependent ...

One possibilities, at least the code is much simpler than yours, is to use  the `tabularray` package (MWE below is tested by version 2022C) with `siunitx` library:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            margin=0.6 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, siunitx}
% \usepackage{mathtools} % not needed in this example
\usepackage[skip=0.33\baselineskip]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Skin-friction co-efficient $Re_{x^{1/2}}C_{F_x}$ with linear stretching $n=1$ and non-linear stretching $n=1.5$ at $A=0.2$, $N_{r}=0.4$, $H=2$, $P_{r}=0.71$, $S_{c}=0.22$, $D_{f}=0.5$ and $S_{r}=1$}
\label{tab:???}
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {*{5}{Q[c, si={table-format=1.1}]} 
                        *{2}{Q[c, si={table-format=1.10}]}},
             colsep  = 12pt,
             row{1,2}= {guard, mode=math}
             }
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    M
    & \SetCell[r=2]{c}  \gamma
            & \SetCell[r=2]{c}  \Tilde{N}
                    & \SetCell[r=2]{c}  \lambda
                            & \SetCell[r=2]{c}  k_{1}
                                    & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  Re_{x^{1/2}}C_{F_x}
                                                    &               \\
    &       &       &       &       & G             & H             \\  
1.1 & 1     & 1     & 1.2   & 0.5   & 0.3664295040  & 0.6593644125  \\ 
1.2 & 1     & 1     & 1.2   & 0.5   & 0.3415189701  & 0.6363362691  \\
1.3 & 1     & 1     & 1.2   & 0.5   & 0.3101361584  & 0.6292554996  \\
1   & 1.1   & 1     & 1.2   & 0.5   & 0.3642452938  & 0.6515014440  \\   
1   & 1.2   & 1     & 1.2   & 0.5   & 0.3619918988  & 0.6444405649  \\
1   & 1     & 1.1   & 1.2   & 0.5   & 0.4139365457  & 0.7091621892  \\ 
1   & 1     & 1.2   & 1.2   & 0.5   & 0.4613301362  & 0.7588005786  \\
1   & 1     & 1     & 1.3   & 0.5   & 0.4660386532  & 0.7627708751  \\
1   & 1     & 1     & 1.4   & 0.5   & 0.5649027509  & 0.8652549292  \\
1   & 1     & 1     & 0.2   & 0.6   & 0.3921955746  & 0.7029730388  \\
1   & 1     & 1     & 0.2   & 0.7   & 0.4025037653  & 0.7326143623  \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, you may liked that table's caption is not wider than table. In this case you should use `talltblr` environment, which s `tabularray` equivalent for "classic" `threeparttable`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            margin=0.6 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=0.33\baselineskip]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Skin-friction co-efficient $Re_{x^{1/2}}C_{F_x}$ with linear stretching $n=1$ and non-linear stretching $n=1.5$ at $A=0.2$, $N_{r}=0.4$, $H=2$, $P_{r}=0.71$, $S_{c}=0.22$, $D_{f}=0.5$ and $S_{r}=1$},
  label = {tab:???}
                ]{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {*{5}{Q[c, si={table-format=1.1}]} 
                        *{2}{Q[c, si={table-format=1.10}]}},
             colsep  = 12pt,
             row{1,2}= {guard, mode=math}
             }
%% table body is the same as above

\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
At the and a fancy version of your table. For exercise of use the `tabularray` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            margin=0.6 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, booktabs, counter, siunitx}
  \ExplSyntaxOn
\NewChildSelector{eachthree}
  {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {6}{3}{\l_tblr_childs_total_tl}
      { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tblr_childs_clist {##1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage[skip=0pt, 
            font = {small, sf},
            labelfont = bf,
            singlelinecheck = off
            ]{caption}

\NewTblrTheme{captionof}%
{\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}%
    {\addtocounter{table}{-1}%
     \captionof{table}{\InsertTblrText{caption}}%
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{talltblr}[
  theme = captionof,
caption = {Skin friction coefficient $Re_{x^{1/2}}C_{F_x}$ with linear stretching $n=1$ and non-linear stretching $n=1.5$ at $A=0.2$, $N_{r}=0.4$, $H=2$, $P_{r}=0.71$, $S_{c}=0.22$, $D_{f}=0.5$ and $S_{r}=1$},
  label = {tab:???}
                ]{colspec = {*{5}{Q[c, si={table-format=1.1}]}
                             *{2}{Q[c, si={table-format=1.10}]}},
                  colsep  = 12pt,
                  row{1,2}= {guard, mode=math},
                  row{3-Z}= {rowsep=0pt},
                  row{eachthree} = {abovesep=1ex},
                 }
    \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    M
    & \SetCell[r=2]{c}  \gamma
            & \SetCell[r=2]{c}  \Tilde{N}
                    & \SetCell[r=2]{c}  \lambda
                            & \SetCell[r=2]{c}  k_{1}
                                    & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  Re_{x^{1/2}}C_{F_x}
                                                    &               \\
    \midrule
    &       &       &       &       & G             & H             \\
    \midrule
1.1 & 1     & 1     & 1.2   & 0.5   & 0.3664295040  & 0.6593644125  \\
1.2 & 1     & 1     & 1.2   & 0.5   & 0.3415189701  & 0.6363362691  \\
1.3 & 1     & 1     & 1.2   & 0.5   & 0.3101361584  & 0.6292554996  \\
1   & 1.1   & 1     & 1.2   & 0.5   & 0.3642452938  & 0.6515014440  \\
1   & 1.2   & 1     & 1.2   & 0.5   & 0.3619918988  & 0.6444405649  \\
1   & 1     & 1.1   & 1.2   & 0.5   & 0.4139365457  & 0.7091621892  \\
1   & 1     & 1.2   & 1.2   & 0.5   & 0.4613301362  & 0.7588005786  \\
1   & 1     & 1     & 1.3   & 0.5   & 0.4660386532  & 0.7627708751  \\
1   & 1     & 1     & 1.4   & 0.5   & 0.5649027509  & 0.8652549292  \\
1   & 1     & 1     & 0.2   & 0.6   & 0.3921955746  & 0.7029730388  \\
1   & 1     & 1     & 0.2   & 0.7   & 0.4025037653  & 0.7326143623  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]